# deadlock even after using ConfigureAwait(false) in Asp.Net flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task-parallel-library, deadlock

I'm hitting deadlock even after using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, below is the sample code.

As per the sample http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html (#Avoding Context), this should not have hit dead lock.

**This is my class**:

```
public class ProjectsRetriever
{
    public string GetProjects()
    {
        ...
        var projects = this.GetProjects(uri).Result;
        ...
        ...
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri)
    {
        return await this.projectSystem.GetProjects(uri, Constants.UserName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

**This class is from a shared library:**

```
public class ProjectSystem
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri, string userName)
    {
        var projectClient = this.GetHttpClient<ProjectHttpClient>(uri);
        var projects = await projectClient.GetProjects();
        // code here is never hit
        ...
}
```

**Works if I add ConfigureAwait(false) to await call in shared library, where HttpClient call is made:**

```
public class ProjectSystem
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri, string userName)
    {
        var projectClient = this.GetHttpClient<ProjectHttpClient>(uri);
        var projects = await projectClient.GetProjects().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // no deadlock, resumes in a new thread.
        ...
}
```

I've been going through all blogs found, only difference I find is ConfigureAwait(false) works when used with httpClient.AsyncApi() call!?

**Please help clarify!!!**

Comment: Your title says *"it doesn't work even when using `ConfigureAwait(false)` but in your code you say the second example works. Which one is it?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: it does not work when used in `ProjectsRetriever` and works when used in `ProjectSystem`

Comment: @user2746890: `I was under assumption, once ConfigureAwait(false) is used (any where in the call stack), execution from that point will not cause deadlock.` It won't capture the context *for that await*. But break out your invocations and awaits, and you'll find that `ProjectSystem.GetProjects` is invoked (and awaits) *before* you call `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the task returned by `GetProjects`. IMO the best answer is "only provide an asynchronous API", i.e., make `ProjectsRetriever.GetProjects()` async.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks very much for clarifying Stephen/Khanh/Yuval!

Comment: I do not understand this post.  `GetProjects()` _(the overload with no parameters)_ is not `async` and does not return a `Task`, so you cannot use `await` on it.  This code is not even valid.

Comment: @BlueRaja, This is a sample code.

Comment: But it's the part of the sample code attempting to explain the problem.  You claim to be having issues `await`ing a synchronous method.  If the method is synchronous, you cannot `await` it, that's a compiler error.  If the method is actually asynchronous, then you should not be using `.Result` to begin with, call `await` instead.  The question makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I need to understand your question better. 
yes, GetProjects() is not async. Where did I use it as async method?
And regarding compiler errors, This is a valid code I've and just renamed class names. Let me know if it failed for you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the comments:

> I was under assumption, once ConfigureAwait(false) is used (any where in the call stack), execution from that point will not cause deadlock.

I don't believe in black magic, and neither should you. Always strive to understand what happens when you use something in your code.

When you `await` an async method that returns a `Task` or a `Task<T>`, there is an implicit capture of the `SynchronizationContext` by the `TaskAwaitable` being generated by the `Task.GetAwaiter` method.

Once that sync context is in place and the async method call completes, the `TaskAwaitable` attempts to marshal the continuation (which is basically the rest of the method calls after the first `await` keyword) onto the `SynchronizationContext` (using `SynchronizationContext.Post`) which was previously captured. If the calling thread is blocked, waiting on that same method to finish, you have a **deadlock**.

You should ask yourself [*Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) 99 percent of the time the answer is **no**. You should use a synchronous API, such as the one `WebClient` offers.

Comment: I have created a library that can easily plugged into your ASP.NET application to detect these deadlocks and help you track them down. More information on https://github.com/ramondeklein/deadlockdetection.

Comment: I could feel your confidence by reading your answer. well answered.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but the article URL was updated to
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/

Answer (score 7):

It blocks when used in `ProjectsRetriever` because:

```
public class ProjectsRetriever
{
    public string GetProjects()
    {
        //querying the result blocks the thread and wait for result.
        var projects = this.GetProjects(uri).Result;
        ... //require Thread1 to continue.
        ...
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri)
    {
        //any thread can continue the method to return result because we use ConfigureAwait(false)
        return await this.projectSystem.GetProjects(uri, Constants.UserName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public class ProjectSystem
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri, string userName)
    {
        var projectClient = this.GetHttpClient<ProjectHttpClient>(uri);
        var projects = await projectClient.GetProjects();
        // code here is never hit because it requires Thread1 to continue its execution
        // but Thread1 is blocked in var projects = this.GetProjects(uri).Result;
        ...
}
```

It does not block when used in `ProjectSystem` because:

```
public class ProjectsRetriever
{
    public string GetProjects()
    {
        ...
        var projects = this.GetProjects(uri).Result;
        ...//requires Thread1 to continue
        ...
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri)
    {
        //requires Thread1 to continue
        return await this.projectSystem.GetProjects(uri, Constants.UserName);
    }
}

public class ProjectSystem
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetProjects(Uri uri, string userName)
    {
        var projectClient = this.GetHttpClient<ProjectHttpClient>(uri);
        var projects = await projectClient.GetProjects().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // no deadlock, resumes in a new thread. After this function returns, Thread1 could continue to run
}
```

Comment: sorry, that's the part confusing me. Is it because HttpClient is making rest call (execution is transferred, not happen in the same context)?

Comment: @user2746890: which part confuses you? In the first example, you call `await projectClient.GetProjects()` with Thread1, so Thread1 must continue the execution but it's BLOCKED in `this.GetProjects(uri).Result;`

Comment: I was under assumption, once ConfigureAwait(false) is used (any where in the call stack), execution from that point will not cause deadlock.

Comment: @user2746890: `ConfigureAwait(false)` only states that any thread other than the awaiting thread can continue the code.

Comment: Calling `Task<T>.Result` will block the calling thread until the task is completed no matter what thread the task is running (or if it is even running) at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. "ConfigureAwait(false)" can not always avoid dead lock.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        // This works !
        ViewBag.Title = GetAsync().Result;

        // This cause deadlock even with "ConfigureAwait(false)" !
        ViewBag.Title = PingAsync().Result;

        return View();
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        return await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<string> PingAsync()
    {
        var pingResult = await new Ping().SendPingAsync("www.google.com", 3).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return pingResult.RoundtripTime.ToString();
    }
}
```

For the above code, "GetAsync()" works while "PingAsync()" doesn't.

But I found that if I wrap the async call into a new task, and wait this task, PingAsync() will work event without "ConfigureAwait(false)":

```
var task = Task.Run(() => PingAsync());
task.Wait();
ViewBag.Title = task.Result;
```

I don't know the reason, maybe someone can tell me the difference.