# hanging in ReadAsync from stream

Tags: c#, async-await, stream

To get my GUI responsive while receiving data I (think I) need to implement the read of a BT device asynchronously.

But once I try to make it async by awaiting `read` it's hanging in the first call or 2nd call.
Debugging also does not produce insights, breakpoint don't fire, etc.

When running synchronously the loop is usually running more than once.

```
public async Task<byte[]> ReadBufferFromStreamAsync(NetworkStream stream)
{
var totalRead = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];

while (!buffer.Contains((byte)'#'))
{
    int read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead);    
    totalRead +=  read;
}
return buffer;
}

 public async Task<string> readAsync()
 {
     string answer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await ReadBufferFromStreamAsync(myStream));
     Debug.Write(answer);
     return answer.Trim(charsToTrim); 
 }

public async Task<string> WriteReadAsync(string str)
{
    Debug.Write($"send:{str},");
    await writeAsync(str);
    var value = await readAsync();
    Debug.Write($"received:{value}");
    return value;
}
```

whereas this runs fine:

```
 ....
 Task<int> read =  stream.ReadAsync(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead);    
 totalRead +=  read.Result;
```

I would be also keen to know how you debug this kind of code in any case of trouble.

Comment: One issue is that you're not `await`ing `ReadAsync`.  And it's possibly some kind of async deadlock, but without seeing all the calls up the chain it's not easy to say where it's happening.

Comment: added it to the Q: awaiting the read does not change the behaviour.

Comment: No, but it is necessary. What calls `ReadBufferFromStreamAsync` and how?

Comment: added it to the Q

Comment: And how is `readAsync` getting called? Is there somewhere up the call hierarchy that _isn't_ `async` ?

Comment: see my modified Q. There is a point in the hierarchy where I use the async Task by waiting for the `.Result`

Comment: At that point in your code, you should either a) make that method `async` if you can, or b) call the task like `var result = myTask().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`. If this solves your issue, then it's a deadlock. If the place where you're calling `.Result` is an event handler for UI, you can change it from `void` to `async void` (`async void` means the method can `await` a task, and that you don't care to wait for the response in the caller).

Comment: please copy your comment as an answer, I will accept it because my code already runs as expected after removing the last `.Result`, reason: exactly as you guessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed with your latest comment, you have an async deadlock. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021304/an-async-await-example-that-causes-a-deadlock) goes into a lot of detail about that and provides links to resources where you can learn more.

You say that somewhere in your code you have something like:

```cs
public void MyMethod()
{
    MyOtherMethodAsync().Result;
}
```

This isn't really the right way to call async methods. You end up with a chicken and egg type situation, where `MyMethod` needs to be free to receive the result of `MyOtherMethodAsync`, so the async method basically waits to resume. The other side of this is `MyMethod`'s call to `.Result` which is blocking, waiting for `MyOtherMethodAsync` to complete. This ends up with them both waiting for each other, and then we have ourselves a deadlock.

The best solution is to make `MyMethod` async:

```cs
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    await MyOtherMethodAsync();
}
```

But this sometimes isn't possible. If the method *has to be sync* then you can use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent it from hanging, but as [Stephen Cleary notes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), it is a hack. Anyway, you can do it like this:

```cs
public void MyMethod()
{
    MyOtherMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Note that for UI event handler methods, you can change them to `async void`:

```cs
public async void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await MyOtherMethodAsync();
}
```

But note that using `async void` effectively means that you don't care about waiting for the result of the `Button1_Clicked` method. It becomes fire and forget. This is, however, the recommended practise for integrating UI buttons, etc. with async methods.

Comment: The `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is effective if you `await` the awaitable. If instead you block with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` [has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372407/still-confused-on-configureawaitfalse-used-with-getawaiter-and-getresult-in-c/54381160#54381160).